# Delete a json inside another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine that I have this kind of JSON object on my react state:

```
this.state={
   parent:{
      childs:[
      child1:{
      },
      child2:{
      },
      child3:null,
       (...)
      ]

   }
}
```

to delete the child1 I did the following method:

```
deleteChild1  = (index,test) => {

    const childs= [...this.state.parent.childs];

    childs[index] = {
        ...childs[index],
        child1: null
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        parent: {
            ...prevState.parent,
            childs: [
                ...childs,
            ]
        }
    }))

}
```

This works with no problem, but imagine that I have 100 childs, I have to do 100 methods like this but instead putting the child1 to null I have to put the child100, child99, you get the idea.

My question is that is another way to put the variable null.

Thanks!

Comment: how does this work? your json / state isn't valid. You have an array with key values?

Comment: John makes a good point, your storing data and infinite list. You need a list of objects not a list of properties. See my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Currently your data structure isn't valid so its hard to write up a solution. **If I try to create that exact state object it raises an exception** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` This is because you have an array written like an object. So first thing to do is adjust your state model to be valid syntax

```
this.state = {
  parent: {
    childs: {
      child1: {
      },
      child2: {
      },
      child3: null,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now, what you are describing / what you want to do is a dynamic key reference.
You can do this like so

```
const childTarget = 'child1'
childs = {
    ...childs,
   [childTarget]: null
}
```

so to abstract that concept a little more. make it a function parameter

```
deleteChild = (childTarget) => {
```

then when you want to remove any particular child you can let them pass their value to this function

```
<Child onRemove={this.deleteChild} name={name} />
// name here would be like 'child1'
// assuming you are looping over state and rendering a child component for each item
```

and when the child calls this function

```
this.props.onRemove(this.props.name)
```

Comment: removed downvote, as you updated your solution. However your solution addresses the question. But the data flow is efficient, the data should be an array with a unique ID, IMO..

Comment: It's actually more efficient than an array because I don't need to traverse the array each time (like a `filter` or a `map` would do).. rather I just do the `O(1)` lookup on an object to remove / assign to null

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, this would be my approach.

Create a function which updates your state with the expect result (removing that property).

If you wish to assign `null` that you can replace `.filter()` with a `.map()` solution. Typically if you are removing a piece of data it does **not** make sense to `null` it, but to remove it.

FYI your property `childs` is an array you have an object within, so you need a list of objects to fix this.

E.g.

```
[
  {
    name: "child1"
  },
  {
    name: "child2"
  },
  {
    name: "child3"
  }
]
```

```
removeChild = (child) => {
  const newChildList = this.state.parent.childs.filter(({name}) => name !== child);

  this.setState(previousState => ({
    ...previousState,
    parent: {
      ...previousState.parent,
      childs: newChildList
    }
  }));
}
```

The key part here is that the data is being updated and overriding the original array. Because you have nested data structure we don’t want to delete any pre-existing data (hence the spreading).

Call the function however you want and if your childs array has an object with the property called `name` that matches the `child` function argument, it will be not be present on the next re-render.

Hope this helps.